# Different Active Users count when using segments

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

I would love to understand what I'm looking at - why are the numbers different in this report when I add a segment?

This is the report without any segmentation:

[image: Without Segments]

This is the same report with the Mobile Traffic segment:

[image: With Segments]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are victim of sampling**:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

Sampling applies when:

- you customize the reports
- the number of sessions for the report time range exceeds 500K (GA) or 100M (GA 360)

The consequence is that:

- the report will be based on a subset of the data (the % depends on the total number of sessions)
- **therefore your report data won't be as accurate as usual**

What you can do to reduce sampling:

- increase sample size in UI (will only decrease sampling to a certain extend, but in most cases won't completely remove sampling)
- reduce time range
- create filtered views so your reports contain the data you need and you don't have to customize them

Comment: This is GA free. Is sampling really the cause of such a huge difference? How come the numbers are much lower in the non-sampled version (above with the green shield icon)?

Comment: Well if all else is equal (time range, filters etc...) and the only thing changing from 1 situation to the other is the fact that your report is sampled, then I don't see another reason. And yes sampling can get really bad. I've seen implementations where e-commerce revenue would simply disappear with sampling, going from `25K` to `0` for a given month!

Answer (score 1):

There two methods that Google uses to identify the number of users.

**Calculation 1**: Pre-calculated data
This calculation relies only on the number of sessions in the given date range and the time of each session. (This is determined by technology managed on the device, like a web browser, and is often referred to as the client-side time.) Because the result of this calculation can be added to the pre-aggregated data tables, Analytics can reference the table to quickly retrieve and serve this data in a report, including when you change the date range.

**Calculation 2**: Data calculated on the fly
Calculation 2 is based on the way you assign, collect, and store persistent data about your traffic. There are many solutions you can implement to customize this, but the most common way this data is going to be assigned and stored is through cookies managed via a web browser.

Adding a segment will force GA to calculate the data on the fly and that's why you are seeing a difference in the numbers.

Are you using GA free or 360? and the time range you are using is same in both reports?

You can also have a look into the Google article https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en

Comment: This is GA free. Is sampling really the cause of such a huge difference? Also how come the numbers are much lower in the non-sampled version (above with the green shield icon)?